# Design tips for a search engine in asp.net/asp.net mvc which vaguely resembles a sharepoint view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Guys i am looking for some awesome tips for developing a page which allows users to search for stuff from the db with the view restricted to only certain columns and the data grouped by and sorted by certain columns..

the source in this case is pretty easy to figure out which is a class which retrieves the search results...kapish..

the view in this case is giving me nightmares as i do not want to write that disgusting piece of code which many asp guys are seemingly used to...overriding row created and data bound of gridview etc etc.... i am thinking of simply rendering a html table itself with the necessary preprocessing applied at the datatable level(group by, sortby etc etc on the in memory object retrieved from the paged results)

i need to know if my thought process so far is right or is there a cleaner way of doing the whole thing in asp.net/asp.net mvc etc etc

Comment: what is exactly the question, do you need search engine or a way to present results ?

Comment: a way to present results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations for not wanting to write "disgusting piece of code"... I spent a few years doing just that and the whole overriding row created / bound / etc. thing is a nightmare.

Your source is a class - great. My preferred method would be to go down the jQuery route, use the jqGrid and write an MVC controller that uses your custom class. Or you could dynamically generate your own HTML table but if you have a lot of data I would save yourself the time and explore jqGrid instead. It doesn't have to be MVC - you could embed it into a standard asp.net website, it's just that the MVC approach makes life easier if you have to expand your application to do more things.

Comment: oopsey..enter wasn't new line.//:|    i also want to group the rows by certain column(s) values....

Comment: Have a look at the jqGrid documentation and examples on the Trirand website (http://www.trirand.com) and see if it fits your needs. I'm not absolutely sure what you mean when you say 'group the rows by certain column values' but I know that the grid supports all the standard functionality you would expect.

Comment: It is indeed awesome. Have a look at http://tpeczek.blogspot.co.uk/ for some more tips and code samples. An upvote on SO would be nice!